# Is data binding with objects from the NGXS state even possible?

Tags: angular, redux, ngxs

I recently introduced NGXS to my project. For the most part im pretty content with the package. However I'm faced with a rather annoying problem. I have a deep object with many of it's properties bound and altered:

```js
export class AnalysisComponent implements OnInit {
  @Select(DeepObjectState) stateObservable$: Observable<DeepObjectStateModel>;
  public deepObject: DeepObjectViewModel;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stateSubscription = this.stateObservable$.subscribe(state => {
      this.deepObject = state.deepObject;
    });
  }
```

Here's a sample of a data bound property:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Some property</mat-label>
  <input matInput [value]="deepObject.someProperty" (input)="deepObject.someProperty= $event.target.value">
</mat-form-field>
```

But now I get the following error, when I try to actually change a property:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'someProperty' of object '[object Object]'`

I understand, that the state is immutable and in dev-mode NGXS is deep freezing the states' properties, therefore the error. Usually to change the state one should dispatch an action to do the job. However to do this for my object would result in a lot of surplus code.

What I want is to retrieve the object from the state, alter it as I used to and when I'm finished dispatch an action to the store to update the whole object. I already tried to work around the deep freeze with a clone using `Object.assign({}, this.deepObject`, but the result was the same.

There must be a simple way to do this, but how?

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck in the same problem but got fixed somehow. I am sharing my service function to fetch data from node.js. please feel free to follow if this helps you.

API function in the controller to get all products. nodejs

```
exports.getAllProducts = (req, res, next) => {
Product.find()
.populate('category')
.populate('attributes')
.populate('creator')
.exec((error, products) => {
    if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
    if(products) {
        res.status(200).json({
            //message: 'products fetch Successfully',
            products
        });
    }
});   }
```

assuming that you know how to set the router in node. if you don't feel free to ask.

my product service.ts to get all product

```
getAllProduct() {  return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.adminProductUrl, {
observe: 'body',
withCredentials: true,
headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type','application/json')})  .pipe(map((data) => {
const productArray: Array<Product> = [];
for(const id in data) {           
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    productArray.push(data[id]);
  }
}
console.log(productArray)          
return productArray;  })) }
```

using .pipe and map before subscribe and looping through the data you can see above code.. do-follow and try for yourself.

I am not sure does this method is the correct way to use with ngxs state management system but I fixed my problem with this.

would like to get a positive answer for my solution whether it is the correct way or not if not then what I missing. please answer. thank you.
hope it helps bro :)